# Random Forest with R : %IncMSE mismatch between varImp(model) and model$importance[,1]

Tags: r, random-forest

I am confused with the different results that I obtain from to functions used with RandomForest package in R to assess variables importance.

My model is defined as :

```
model <- randomForest(nee_m ~ ., data = nee, ntree = 200, mtry = 7, importance=TRUE)
```

nee_m is the main variable, and the 8 explanatory variables are sw_in, ta, vpd, rew, rh, pluie, vent, co2.

Here are my results:
(1) using varImp(model), the result for %IncMSE is:

> ```
>       Overall
> ```
>
> ta      118.08770
>
> rh       71.48408
>
> vpd      62.24601
>
> pluie    23.28636
>
> vent    151.23066
>
> sw_in   886.14511
>
> co2     208.20772
>
> rew     305.57892

(2) using model$importance[order(model$importance[, 1], decreasing = TRUE), ]: the result is:

> ```
>         %IncMSE IncNodePurity
> ```
>
> sw_in   43.12005718   1451599.722
>
> vpd      4.70746641    201849.024
>
> rew      4.16280001    189716.854
>
> ta       4.02571339    121612.437
>
> rh       2.73049849    102672.109
>
> co2      1.37747947     81391.062
>
> vent     0.57235041     61368.274
>
> pluie    0.02396995      2851.669

If I put (1) in the decreasing order as in (2) and calculate the relative value: I get (3):

> ```
>       Overall
> ```
>
> sw_in   48.522222 %
>
> rew     16.732438 %
>
> co2     11.400730 %
>
> vent    8.2808645 %
>
> ta      6.4660714 %
>
> rh       3.914219 %
>
> vpd      3.408375 %
>
> pluie    1.275080 %

Values and order of importance between (2) and (3) are different, which results should I trust and why are they different? I may miss somthing in the understanding of the results.

Thanks in advance for helping

EDIT:
Very strange result:
if I set: varImp(model, **scale=FALSE**), I get excatly the same result as (2) in terms of values and order! so a value between 0 and 100, which is the opposite of what is explained in the documentation: i.e. if you set scale=FALSE, the value should not be between 0 and 100, but only if you set default varImp(model) (or varImp(model, scale=TRUE), then it is supposed to be between 0 and 100...
This is not what I have in (3)...
So, which results make sense then?
I am really confused...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888619/difference-between-varimp-caret-and-importance-randomforest-for-random-fores

Comment: Yes I saw, that thank you, but their RF is based on classification (nodepurity) and note regression, I don't really see any clear explanation, or at least, it is still not clear too me...I am working on it

Comment: Do you mean varImpPlot()? There is not varImp() function in the randomForest package.

Comment: True there is not, but you can use varImp() if the object you put inside is a random forest model from what I understand. Actually I downloaded "caret" package, and then I can use varImp() on my random forest model saved as model, which was built with the randomForest function (randomForest package indeed)